# Why server doesn't get the file (PDF filled form) sent from pdf submit button to url?

Tags: javascript, php, pdf

I created a PDF form through Acrobat DC and my submit button is not working as expected. I want to send my filled document to an URL as a full PDF form and at the same time as a XFDF. On my server side, I get the connexion log but no file (or data) is sent.

I've been reading a lot and I believe everything is correctly setup in the dialogue box in Acrobat. I've been previously using the mailto option and it's working fine, but I really want to send it to my server directly instead (URL).

Here's a screen capture of log : https://ibb.co/NpcGtLV

My ultimate goal is to compile everything in a database. I'm gonna create a user interface eventually to be able to filter the data but also be able to download the original PDF form filled.

Anyone can help plz??

Here's the acrobat Javascript detail :

- [1st Setup for the send button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46dnj.png)
- [2nd Setup for the send button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECCGR.png)

Here's the PHP source code :

```
$files = $_FILES;
$post = $_REQUEST;
$log .= print_r($files, true)." ".print_r($files,true)." ".PHP_EOL;
```

Then we save and print log.

Comment: Can you post your source code?

Comment: Can you share the pdf in question?

Comment: I did include some code lines. I can't share the PDF as it is for internal use of my client.

Comment: I don't know about the Acrobat dialogs you show, I'd need the actual form related objects in the PDF to tell for sure. Nonetheless, have you yet analyzed the raw body of those posts? Either as proposed by @Jan's answer or inspecting a TCP dump? After all, according to the logs you appear to use plain http, not https?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `php://input` stream wrapper to read the raw data from the request body:

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Take care that you validate the input!